# Returning the value that for statement prints

Tags: java

I would like to return all the information as output that the for statement prints.

For instance:

```
public static int countNumbers(int x) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    return SOMETHING; // This something should be the values for statements prints.
                      // For example, countNumbers(5) returns 12345.
}
```

So when I call the method somewhere else, I will get the output.

So:

```
int output = countNumbers(3);
//output = 123;
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` to accumulate the result. **Update:** Then convert it to int using `Integer.parseInt`:

```
public static int countNumbers(int i) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
      buf.append(i);
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(buf.toString());
}
```

Note that this works only for fairly small values of `i` (up to 9), otherwise you will get an integer overflow.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but my output has to be int. This example gives an output as a String. Shall I cast?

Comment: @Dave You could convert Péter's result using [Integer.parseInt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Comment: @Dave, see my update. @Zach, my first suggestion was `valueOf`, but `parseInt` is indeed better, thanks :-)

Comment: @Dave: This makes no sense. Replace 5 by 42 and enjoy the overflow.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. May I do this without using any method (without using StringBuilder, etc.) at all? May I do it using arrays?

Comment: @Dave, you can also use string concatenation, like in `String s = ""; s += i;`, but it is slower because it creates a new `String` object every time. Although in this limited case you won't notice the performance difference. Note though that under the hood this will also get trasnlated into a method call, namely `String.concat()`.

Comment: Thanks, I never thought concatenation, it's better.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public static int countNumbers(int x) {

    int retVal = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        retVal += i * Math.pow(10, x - i); // Is it math? I'm a C++ programmer
    }

    return retVal;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public static int countNumbers(int x) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        result *= 10;
        result += i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 Ah, this one is much more optimized than that earlier answer I posted!